# Which is the easiest way to migrate entire List to a new new site?

Tags: list, wss-3.0, migration

Hi

I need to migrate a list with 800+ items to a new location but within the same site collection. Which is the easiest way to do it. I want it to be a exactly same with all data, attachements etc intact.

I use WSS 3.0

Please help me out.

Thanks

-saumil

Comment: what about if i want to export calendar, lists and other data from one sharepoint to another, where we have different sharepoint 2010 versions, servers and Domain. Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Sean says one option is to make a template, and create a new list using that.

http://grounding.co.za/blogs/neil/archive/2008/10/05/moving-a-list-with-content-between-sharepoint-servers.aspx

If its simple you can perhaps use the DataSheet view to copy and paste the data to the new list if you've already setup the structure.

You can IIRC do a similar thing with SharePoint Designer.

You can also look at the [STSADM gl-exportlist and gm-importlist extensions](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/09/importexportcopy-lists/).

Comment: Yes, you can click "include content" to ship the data within the template.

Comment: Thx Ryan, Is it possible that if a list is say 100+ mb.... all data appended columns etc will migrate properly using STSADM command you mentioned... In short, I need a mirror copy of the list... will that happen following your commands? Thx again!

Comment: I've used gl-export/import list very successfully in the past but not for a list that size - I would think its your best bet though. Why don't you give it a go and let us know how it works for you?

Comment: You cannot migrate this way if you have lookup columns in the list.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard tool by Chris O'Brien on CodePlex.

http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

You can backup/restore from individual files/lists/libraries all the way up to full site collections.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know (in SP2007) is to recreate the list at the destination - temporarily make a temate from the original if it's complex, it it needs all the custom colums and formulas - the use the content and structure tool.

Remove the template ehen you're done, unless it's a gpod idea to keep the template available...

Answer (score 2):

Checkout Metalogix Site Migration Manager (I don't work for them). In most scenarios moving content around while maintaining full fidelity is key. I am sure we can script everything this product does but it really provides a lot of options to choose from before running the job.

Comment: by full fidelity I meant preserving Created By, Created Date, Modified By, Modified Date etc..

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall whether WSS 3.0 has content and structure mode, but you can create an empty list (if your source is a custom list, create a new and empty custom list, if it's a task list, create a new and empty task list, etc.) and, using Content and Structure mode, move the items to the new empty list. The metadata will all carry over - just not the views.