# List template that includes formatting

Tags: list-template, formatting

Is there a way to make a template of a list that includes formatting using out of the box tools or designer.

Answer (score 1):

You can only save a list definition as a template with the option to include the existing data in that list(include content). You can find out more [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/copy-or-move-a-list-by-using-a-list-template-HA101782479.aspx). What do you mean by formatting?.

Comment: No. I mean is there a way to save the html formatting.  I have my list that I formatted thru designer to look nicer.  I have several fields in column 1 (Heading, Price, Desc), a picure in column 2. Picture contains a link to a url in the list.  I was wondering if I could save all that and use it with other list (so long as the column names are the same)

Comment: Check out this thread - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11443/how-to-move-a-list-both-structure-and-content-from-one-server-to-another-quickl

Comment: Not quite what I meant but thank you anyways